# Newest version of nodejs is not intalling in Linux Mint Tina

Tags: linux-mint, node.js

**Environment**

Linux Mint 19.2 Tina 84_x64

**Installation**

```
$curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 10.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Ign:4 http://packages.linuxmint.com tina InRelease                       
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease          
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease        
Hit:7 http://packages.linuxmint.com tina Release                        
Reading package lists... Done                     

## Confirming "tina" is supported...

+ curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x/dists/tina/Release'

## Your distribution, identified as "tina", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support
```

**Installing Nodejs**

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ nodejs --version
v8.10.0
```

LTS version 10x is not installed?

Comment: which part of this message do you not understand? ... 
`## Your distribution, identified as "tina", is not currently supported`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installation script that you downloaded needs to be adjusted so that it knows about **tina** being a bionic release.

First, download the script:
`wget https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x`

Then, open the file in your favorite editor. Scroll down until you find a section that begins with `check_alt`. Look for a line that looks like this:

`check_alt "Linux Mint"    "tessa"    "Ubuntu" "bionic"`

Add this line right below it:

`check_alt "Linux Mint"    "tina"    "Ubuntu" "bionic"`

After saving, run `chmod +x setup_10.x`. Now you can run this script as normal.

Comment: $ wget https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x , works for me. Then you need to $ sudo ./setup_10.x and $ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Comment: This is a shame. Years and years later, it's equal. All that to say hello world. Young coders, move out of node, it's garbage.